# How I can use future field in class (Flutter, Dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have database sqlite3 with a two tables:

| Product | Photos |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| name | product_id |
|  | data(base64 |

The function, where I get all products:

```
Future<List<Product>?> getAllProducts() async {
   textQuery = "SELECT * FROM Product limit 100"; 
   var res = await db!.rawQuery(textQuery);
   List<Product>? list = res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Product.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];
   retrun list;
}
```

The model Product:

```
class Product {
  late int id;
  late String name;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
  );
}
```

And I use FutureBuilder to show this products. But I need show a picture in my list.
What way is right in this situation?

I tried this code in model:

```
late Image _image;

Image imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
  return Image.memory(base64Decode(base64String));
}

void initAsync() async {
  Photo photo = await DBProvider.db.getMainPhoto(id);
  _image = imageFromBase64String(photo.data);
}
```

And this code in widget:

```
Future<bool> _getList() async {
  listOfProducts = (await DBProvider.db.getAllProducts(selectedCategory))!;
  for (Product product in listOfProducts) {
    product.initAsync();
  }
}
```

But my app is frozen

Comment: You are probably missing `await` here: `product.initAsync();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code into:

```
Future<void> initAsync() async {
  Photo photo = await DBProvider.db.getMainPhoto(id);
  _image = imageFromBase64String(photo.data);
}

Future<bool> _getList() async {
  listOfProducts = (await DBProvider.db.getAllProducts(selectedCategory))!;
  for (Product product in listOfProducts) {
    await product.initAsync();
  }
}
```

but this will only fetch the pictures from the DB, I don't know how you plan to show them, but if the picture will remain on the `product` object, you can simply create a getter for your `_image` variable, and use that to display the image